# Delete all parent-children Entities connected by one-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm

```
in CalcResult entity

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\CalcResult",inversedBy="buySellResults",cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="calcResult_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $calcResult;


in BuySellResult entity 

        /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\BuySellResult",mappedBy="calcResult",cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $buySellResults;
```

`CalcResult` row has some `BuySellResult`,These two entries have the relationship like parent-children.

I would like to delete all `BuySellResult` rows connected with one `CalcResult` row, when I delete one `CalcResult` row.

However when I try to delete `CalcResult` row,

This error happens.
How can I solve it?

I added the `cascade={"persist"}`,but I am not sure it is the correct way to  my goal.

```
[3/4] ForeignKeyConstraintViolationException: An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM CalcResult WHERE id = ?' with params [1004]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`wisdom`.`buysellresult`, CONSTRAINT `FK_C1A2F7B3CFB4BB7` FOREIGN KEY (`calcResult_id`) REFERENCES `CalcResult` (`id`))   +
```

Comment: Uh … is it possible that the code you’ve posted doesn’t match your description? What’s the parent entity and what’s the child? By the way, your `JoinColumn` is redundant, you can omit it altogether as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
cascade={"persist"}
```

to

```
cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true
```

More details here:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal